# Search for files and copy them to another folder (Thunar)

Tags: xfce, thunar

I know it sounds like a stupid question, but really, how do I search for files (for instance, I want to find all files that have "python" in the name) in a folder using Thunar? I know there is "Search" (catfish search tool) when you right click the window, but you can't copy the files you found.

I'm using Ubuntu Xfce.

Answer (score 0):

Where Thunar may struggle with your needs the command line will not. To illustrate this I have created a directory filled with 'pythonesque' files, except for one:

```
andrew@illium~/test$ ls -1
blah_blah_python.jpg
ordinary_file.txt
python_rulz.txt
test_python.txt
andrew@illium~/test$
```

Now to copy all of the python related filenames to another directory, leaving our *non-python* file *uncopied*:

```
andrew@illium~/test$ cp -v *python* $HOME/another_directory/
'blah_blah_python.jpg' -> '/home/andrew/another_directory/blah_blah_python.jpg'
'python_rulz.txt' -> '/home/andrew/another_directory/python_rulz.txt'
'test_python.txt' -> '/home/andrew/another_directory/test_python.txt'
andrew@illium~/test$
```

Note that the *non-python* named file has been excluded. Perhaps this will suit your needs better rather than trying to massage Thunar beyond its modest capabilities?

Comment: Well typing in command line won't satisfy my needs, but thanks. I've got a lot of processing to do, so I need a GUI. Was it a good idea to uninstall Thunar and install Nautilus?

Comment: @nuked0ne Thunar is a little basic I guess but I am not convinced that Nautilus would be more useful for your purpose. Hopeful a GUI File Manager expert will come along with a more useful answer :)